# Possible to save mongoose large data into multiple files

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to store mongoose large data into multiple documents but should be under one collection

for example

-->Collection --> Customers and it has documetns based on ObjectId.

so what I am looking for is it possible to store data into multiple docs but all of them should be linked together? my problem is my server "throws error when customer makes really large request and save data, so I need solution to store that large data.

```
drives:[{
name:string,
driveID:string,
phases:[] // this contain sub arrays and can be upto 20k lines of JSON because it contains a questionnaire
}]
```

for example

```
"phases":[
{
"phase":"abc"
  "phase" : "driveOne",
   "text" : "Drive One",
    "textKey" : "",
    "index" : "1.0",
    "subjects":[
    "id:"1.1.1",
    "text":"test",
    "textKey":"",
]
},

// for demo purpose I am copying same data...
{
"phase":"abc"
  "phase" : "driveOne",
   "text" : "Drive One",
    "textKey" : "",
    "index" : "1.0",
    "subjects":[
    "id:"1.1.1",
    "text":"test",
    "textKey":"",
]
},
{
"phase":"abc"
  "phase" : "driveOne",
   "text" : "Drive One",
    "textKey" : "",
    "index" : "1.0",
    "subjects":[
    "id:"1.1.1",
    "text":"test",
    "textKey":"",
]
},
{
"phase":"abc"
  "phase" : "driveOne",
   "text" : "Drive One",
    "textKey" : "",
    "index" : "1.0",
    "subjects":[
    "id:"1.1.1",
    "text":"test",
    "textKey":"",
]
},

]
```

Comment: Did your Data is having `_id` or you are not concern with `_id`  .

Comment: not in the model but yes i can access the document using _id

Comment: Can you please provide the data ? that is large ? i want to see the structure .

Comment: Okkk will get back to you with solution .

Comment: waht error do you get?

Comment: It would be clear from the error that you get but do consider that the large dataset limitation might not be from mongodb/mongoose and node instead. If this update really ahs large dataset you might want to read it chunks and send query (from a json file may be).

Answer (score 0):

Here you can update your document in the for loop.

In my example change the necessary keywords according to your DataBase:

```
userController.signUp = async function(req,res){
    req.body.installation = [
    {
        "phase":"abc",
        "phase" : "driveOne",
        "text" : "Drive One",
        "textKey" : "",
        "index" : "1.0",
        "subjects":[{
        "id":"1.1.1",
        "text":"test",
        "textKey":"",
        }]
    },


    {
        "phase":"abc",
        "phase" : "driveOne",
        "text" : "Drive One",
        "textKey" : "",
        "index" : "1.0",
        "subjects":[{
        "id":"1.1.1",
        "text":"test",
        "textKey":"",
        }]
    },
    {
        "phase":"abc",
        "phase" : "driveOne",
        "text" : "Drive One",
        "textKey" : "",
        "index" : "1.0",
        "subjects":[{
        "id":"1.1.1",
        "text":"test",
        "textKey":"",
        }]
    },
    {
        "phase":"abc",
        "phase" : "driveOne",
        "text" : "Drive One",
        "textKey" : "",
        "index" : "1.0",
        "subjects":[{
        "id":"1.1.1",
        "text":"test",
        "textKey":"",
        }]
    },

    ]
    //Your DB name instead of userModel
    userModel.findOne({_id: "5d1d9691019db61515450574"})
    .exec(async (err , found)=>{
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            for(var i = 0; i< req.body.installation.length; i++){
                var hey = req.body.installation[i];
                found.installation[i] = req.body.installation[i];
                console.log("=============================+>" ,found.installation)
                await userModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: found._id} , found, {upsert: true , new: true});

            }
            res.send(found);
        }
    });

}
```

I have tried using 2000 thousand records and it doesn't gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb can handle large amount of requests. If your server has high configuration like RAM>= 8GB, then it would works fine. The problem with single document is it stores upto 16 MB data. If exeeded then again we have to shard it. Simple solution is store data in multiple documents.If you are fetching huge data at one time then you have to paginate it. For calculations like total size etc then you can use aggregate queries. I've tested on 9,00,000 documents in single collection.My aggregate query responds within 300 MS while normal find takes 2.20 to 3 Minutes.

Pagination e:g-

```
 req.body.pageNo = 1
 req.body.pageSize = 100

  .skip(req.body.pageSize * ((req.body.pageNo === 0 ? 1 :  req.body.pageNo) - 1))
  .limit(req.body.pageSize)
```